# CGContextShowTextAtPoint: invalid context

Tags: objective-c, iphone, quartz-2d

I want to call a method responsible for drawing text on screen after each 5 seconds. Here is my code

```
-(void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *)timer
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0); 
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor); 

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 145.0, 240.0);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0); 
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(context, 1);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);


    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5,0.5,1,1);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 100, 100, "01", 2);
}
```

But after 5 seconds when this method is called i am getting this error
CGContextShowTextAtPoint: invalid context

Another thing is how to show a thinner font?

Comment: how to format code so it looks perfect in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, it's always a good idea to clear the graphics context before drawing to it.

```
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextClearRect(context, theRectInWhichYouWillBeDrawing);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to **have** a context before drawing into it. Putting draw code inside of `drawRect` does this automatically for you (you get `drawRect` when you subclass UIView).

You can make your own context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize size)`, although it can get problematic making sure that your context stays a valid one.

Sure is problematic for me at the moment, anyway. Anyone knowing more about this want to weigh in?